# Accidentally removed SUNWcsr

Tags: unix, solaris

I have accidentally removed the SUNWcsr, SUNWhea as well as SUNWmdb and SUNWmdbx while the most unfortunate thing is the network connection breaks which makes me unable to login to the system again. How can I install  those package back?

I have then reboot the server and of coz it won't boot and keep on having core dump. I have then boot to single user mode using the installation cd and then fix the disk using fsck. After that, I then tried to mount the disk using "mount /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0 /a" and it works.

I can then locate the SUNWcsr while when I issue the command "pkgadd -R /a -d . SUNWcsr" it compained with "error: unable to open admin file  "

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Did you cd to the location of the SUNWcsr package directory ?

Edit

The problem is most likely that you are missing the file `/var/sadm/install/admin/default`
you can get a copy of it from `/a/var/sadm/install/admin`

eg

```
mkdir -p /var/sadm/install/admin/
cp /a/var/sadm/install/admin/default /var/sadm/install/admin/default
```

Once you've done that the pkgadd command should work. Just in case the one on /a is missing here's a copy of it from my system

```
#
# Copyright 2004 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
# Use is subject to license terms.
#
#ident  "@(#)default    1.7     04/12/21 SMI"
#
mail=
instance=unique
partial=ask
runlevel=ask
idepend=ask
rdepend=ask
space=ask
setuid=ask
conflict=ask
action=ask
networktimeout=60
networkretries=3
authentication=quit
keystore=/var/sadm/security
proxy=
basedir=default
```

Comment: finally, according to SUN's engineer, he recommend us to reinstall the solaris 8 which we finally did that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-a none` to not use an admin file. You also should use `-R /a` or try to run pkgadd from a chroot in `/a` (I forget if that's possible.)